# Missing lifetime specifier in type parameter

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have the following function (simplified minimal example - Sender & channel() are the standard library versions):

```
use pnet::packet::ethernet::EthernetPacket; // 0.22.0
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};

pub fn start_sender() -> (Sender<EthernetPacket>) {
    let (sender, _) = channel();
    (sender)
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:4:34
  |
4 | pub fn start_sender() -> (Sender<EthernetPacket>) {
  |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider giving it a 'static lifetime: `EthernetPacket + 'static`
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
```

I have no idea why (it appears to be the same as the return method `std::sync::mpsc::channel()` itself uses), nor how to fix it?

This seems simple, but I have searched, read documentation, read the error description, and nothing seems to point towards the solution. Note, none of the suggested duplicates are applicable in this case, the syntax required in the solution is different (see comments).

Edit: I found this question, which it may actually be a partial duplicate of (in terms of semantics if not syntax): [Rust Lifetimes with mpsc::Sender<T<'a>> and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511332/rust-lifetimes-with-mpscsenderta-and-threads)

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There isn't enough information about the types here. The [Rust tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) contains more help.

Comment: @mcarton not too sure what you mean, it was already pretty minimal, I'm away from my development machine, but have removed the ellipses and added an import to the library I was using.

Comment: There are 4 letters in MCVE, your example only cared about 2 of them. Ideally you should post an example which creates exactly the error you have. Right now we still have no idea what `Sender` is, nor what the `channel` function returns ("it appears to be the same as the return method `std::sync::mpsc::channel()` itself uses" is confusing, is it that function or is it not?).

Comment: [`EthernetPacket`](https://docs.rs/pnet/0.22.0/pnet/packet/ethernet/struct.EthernetPacket.html) has a lifetime parameter. You have to specify it in your function declaration.

Comment: The duplicates applied to your case: `pub fn start_sender<'p>() -> (Sender<EthernetPacket<'p>>)`

Comment: Note that your "MCVE" didn't have the correct import statements (`pnet::ethernet::EthernetPacket` is not valid), so it's self-evident how much time you spent trying to produce a representative example. It's a good idea to put as much effort into the *question* as you'd appreciate from an *answer*.

Comment: @mcarton as clearly stated in my question it is the obvious one from the standard library.

Comment: @mcarton the key question is how to add a lifetime parameter to a type parameter? None of the supposed duplicates cover that.

Comment: @Shepmaster none of the duplicates state how to add a lifetime parameter to a non-reference type parameter?  Also, as clearly stated in the comments, I was away from my development machine, so made an effort to edit my question in response to the comments, I apologise for not being a compiler.

Comment: @Shepmaster thank you very much, adding the lifetime parameter in angled brackets after the type parameter is the solution.  Unfortunately that solution doesn't appear in any of the supposed 'duplicates' so if you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted (and also fix my MCVE - no point putting much effort into a question that is just going to be marked as a duplicate).

Comment: @Shepmaster I've come up against a similar problem again, I was wondering if you could explain why I need a lifetime (as the new object is returned, isn't ownership returned to the calling function, so it should just get its lifetime from that function by elision)?

Comment: I found an actual partial duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511332/rust-lifetimes-with-mpscsenderta-and-threads